# Running the same RNN over two tensors in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to run the same RNN over two tensors in tensorflow. My current solution looks like this:

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(cell_size)

with tf.variable_scope("encoder", reuse=None):
    out1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, tensor1, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.variable_scope("encoder", reuse=True):
    out2 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, tensor2, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Is this is the best way to ensure that the weights between the two RNN ops are shared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that is basically how I would do it.  For a really simple model like this it does not matter much but for a more complicated model I would define a function to build the graph.

```
def makeEncoder(input_tensor):
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(cell_size)
    return tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, tensor1, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:
    out1 = makeEncoder(tensor1)
    scope.reuse_variables()
    out2 = makeEncoder(tensor2)
```

The other way to do it would be to use `tf.cond(...)` as a switch to change between the inputs based on a boolean placeholder.  They would then go to just one output.  I have found that this can get a bit messy.  Also you would need to provide both inputs even if you really only need one.  I think my first solution is the best.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!