# Use same RNN twice

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, graph, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to run the same RNN cell over two inputs in Tensorflow.
My code:

```
    def lstm_cell():
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(self.hidden_size, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)

    self.forward_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_cell() for _ in range(layers)], state_is_tuple=True)
    self.initial_state = self.forward_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)

    outputs1, state1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.forward_cell, input1, initial_state=self.initial_state)

    outputs2, state2 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.forward_cell, input2, initial_state=self.initial_state)
```

My question now is, is this the correct code to do what I want (use the SAME RNN on both inputs, i.e. share the weights).
On a similar post I found a similar solution using `reuse_variables()`: [Running the same RNN over two tensors in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40447227/running-the-same-rnn-over-two-tensors-in-tensorflow)

I would go for that, but with my current solution I do not get a reuse error, which confuses me. When I print my variables it seems to be fine, too.
Could you explain why there is no reuse error in my case, and if this is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

After I double checked the source code in 1.6, I found that my memories from early versions are no longer actual (so thanks for bringing this up!). Your code indeed reuses the cell variables, because cells are *initialized lazily and only once* (see [`RNNCell.build()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/RNNCell#build) method, which actually creates the kernel and bias). After the cell is built, it's *not* rebuilt upon the next call. This means that a single instance of a cell always holds the same variables, no matter how often it's used in different networks, until you manually reset the `built` state. That's why `reuse` parameter no longer matters.

**Original answer (no longer valid):**

Your current code creates two independent RNN layers (each one is deep), with same initial state. This means they have different weight matrices, different nodes in graph, etc. Tensorflow has nothing to complain about, because it doesn't know they are intended to be shared. That's why you should specify `reuse=True` before calling `tf.dynamic_rnn` as the question you refer to suggests, this will cause tensorflow share the kernels of all cells.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is the point I do not understand. If this was the case, why do I only see one set of variables for the RNN (when I print my variables). Further, if Tensorflow does not know the variables intend to be equal, I do not see how reuse changes that. In my opinion when I try to create multiple variables with the same name without using reuse, it gives an error, and I can control the behavior with reuse. But if they variables would be different (i.e. Tensorflow not giving an error), reuse could not change anything.

Comment: @Gemini You are right, my original answer is no longer actual. See an update

Comment: thanks a lot, that's very helpful! Last question for clarification then: If I would want different cells, I would just use different scopes right?

Comment: Yes, use different cells and different scopes